# Cannot deploy a new war file to beanstalk via Terraform

Tags: deployment, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create a new beanstalk environment via Terraform and have it run a specified `war` file. With my terraform configuration script, I can create the beanstalk environment and I can also upload the `war` file to an S3 bucket. However, I am unable to deploy this war file to this newly created beanstalk environment.

Here is my TF configuration.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "myjar" {
  bucket = "mybucketname"
  key    = "jars/myapp-1.0.war"
  source = "localdir/myapp-1.0.war"
  etag   = "${md5(file("localdir/myapp-1.0.war"))}"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "myjarversion" {
  application = "MyBeanstalkApplication"
  name = "1.0"
  bucket = "mybucketname"
  key = "jars/myapp-1.0.war"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tftestenv" {
  name                = "myapp-tftest"
  application         = "MyBeanstalkApplication"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.2 running Tomcat 8 Java 8"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = "1"
  }
  ... # bunch of other beanstalk settings
}
```

Terraform successfully picks up the local file `localdir/myapp-1.0.war`, uploads to S3 in the appropriate bucket and key and also associates the war file as a version in my beanstalk application (I can see the war listed in beanstalk application versions list when viewed through the AWS console).

It also creates a the `myapp-tftest` environment for my application but does not deploy the `war` file to it.

What am I missing here? Or is it not possible to deploy a version to a beanstalk environment via terraform (which would be disappointing).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize there was an option called `version_label` through which the application version could be specified.

Closing the issue.